# How to change value in google sheet function

Tags: google-sheets

I was trying to countif the order in the sheet.
the sheet name indicates the day in month January.
column A indicates the date (D MMM) the order taking place.
therefore I use the function below for 1 Jan

```
=countifs('1'!A:A,B2)
```

I wanted to know if its possible to change the function to

```
=countifs('X'!A:A,B2)
```

X being the date of the order in Column A.

Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fS0WUEm-CD3YljH55SgjjTq0JQG0FerEOoY2YaVbTUA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Use `INDIRECT()` function.

```
=Countifs(INDIRECT(LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2)-1)&"!A:A"),B2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method to extract the numbers from A2:

`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(REGEXEXTRACT(text(A2,"d mmm"),"\d")&"!A:A"),B2)`

If you were able to consolidate all of your tabs onto one tab, then you could have an `ARRAYFORMULA` that would get all of your `COUNTIF` without needing to drag down the formula.

A consolidated tab would therefore need 'Order date' and 'Order number' columns.